# two charset in one website,how to parse

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i was study python scraping knowledge recently,and i want to scrap a website

[a website with two charset,utf-8 and gb2312](http://news.sina.com.cn/)

i get the warning from beautifulsoup:

> Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

i google the problem and i think it may be the decode problem,my code can scrap other website smoothly.

so ,what should i do?

this is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


code_type = 'utf-8'
html = urlopen("http://news.sina.com.cn/")
print(html)

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser",from_encoding=code_type)

imglist = bsObj.findAll("img")
print(imglist)
```

Comment: When you say "both on the same page"… Do you mean that one HTML document contains characters encoded in both charsets? That should be impossible and not render properly anywhere. Or are you saying *some specific pages on sina.com.cn are encoded in UTF-8 and others in GB2312?* Then the HTTP header and/or meta tag will tell you which one it is, otherwise no browser could render it properly either.

Comment: What are you trying to scrape? The gbk seems only related to some script tags where the encoding in the js files is gbk, the charset of the html is utf-8. Also I think a bigger problem than you have now is that there is a delay before the content is rendered so you won't get the actual source regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Detect the page coding before parsing it.

Reference to chardet repo
https://github.com/chardet/chardet.

You should't set the code_type as utf-8 for all pages, detect the right encoding of page and modify it to the right one.

Encoding detecting might be failed sometime. In that case, you should prepare a dict to store known websites' encoding and use the dict while parsing special pages.

Comment: i have try your solution……but ,the result of chardet is {'encoding': None, 'confidence': 0.0}

Comment: Encoding detecting is hard, so it might be failed sometime. In that case, you should prepare a dict to store known websites' encoding and use the dict while parsing special pages.

Comment: @dogewang and I tried the chardet  for  'http://news.sina.com.cn/', got the right result:  {'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}.

Comment: i open the webset and use the developertools to search the keyword"charset" in the page html, and i found utf-8 and gb2312,i think i have checked the charset manually.the problem is how to deocde the whole page in proper situation partially

Comment: yes……I try it again and get the answer.but,when i use utf-8 to decode it ,i get the error message

Comment: Using requests to get html and decoded success. r = requests.get(url)   r.content.decode('utf-8')